# Problems Implementing Search Bar with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I tried to implement a search bar with Parse from a project I found on Google but I have a problem.

The two lines where it says `//my problem` is causing the app to crash

```
if (self.canSearch == 0) {
//my problem   query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
} else {
//my problem   query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
}
```

in the

```
-(PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *query;
    if (self.canSearch == 0) {
        query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    } else {
        query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    }

    NSString *searchThis = [_searchedBar.text lowercaseString];

    [query whereKey:@"item1" containsString:searchThis];

    }

    [query orderByAscending:@"item1"];

    // If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
    if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    }

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    return query;
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong because it works in the project I am working for.

This is what it says in the console when the app crashes

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: You say "this line of code crashes my app" but you posted 4 lines. Which of the 4 lines causes the crash? And update your question with details of the crash. What's the complete and exact error message?

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained. Instead of linking to your entire project, please include the information that rmaddy asked for above.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: The two lines where it says `//my problem` in `(self.canSearch == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Those lines you've identified are almost certainly not the problem.  Kind of a magic trick here:  `NSLog(@"%@", _searchedBar);` will probably reveal that `_searchedBar` is undefined, therefore `.text`, therefore the parameter to `whereKey` which causes the crash.

Also note that:

```
if (anything) {
    something
} else {
    something
}
```

Can be stated more concisely as:

```
something
```

Comment: Its definitely the two lines of `query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];` thats causing the crash. I have uncommented the first line of `query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];` and the app runs as normal but doesnt load the objects